# Map JSON to OBJECT by usong JackSon

Tags: java, jackson, json

exmaple.file

I want to map the following json to object. I have tried with custom object by using Jackson.

```
[
    {
    "widgetTitle":"Bannerfgfg",
     "widgetCode" : "PRTIMG001",
    "widgetType":"dssdsd",
    "widGetSpanNumber":"2",
    "jqimagePath":"images/slider/",
    "jqimageCount":"4",
    "jqimageHeight":"300"
    },
    {
     "widgetTitle" : "Favourites",
     "widgetCode" : "Favourites",
     "widgetType" : "sdsdsd",                           
     "widgetAttributes":{
        {"key":"loadTemplate","value":[{"url" : "favourites"}]
        },
        {"key":"loadCntId","value": "tobeloaded"}
        }
    },
    {
        "widgetTitle" : "Exchange Rates",           
        "widgetCode" : "sdsdsd",
        "widgetType" : "sdsdsdsdsd",
        "widgetAttributes": {
            {"key":"datatype","value": "json"},
            {"key":"appCode","value": "mst"},
            {"key":"url","value":"exchangeMaster/getCurrencyExchangeDetail?"},
            {"key":"colNames" ,"value":["Form CCY","To CCY","Ex RT","Prd FRM","Prd TO"]},
            {"key":"colModel","value":[ {"name" : "fromCurrencyCode","index" : "fromCurrencyCode","align":"center"},
                        {"name" : "toCurrencyCode","index" : "toCurrencyCode","align":"center"},
                        {"name" : "exchangeRate",   "index" : "exchangeRate","align":"right"},
                        {"name" : "periodFrom","index" : "periodFrom"},                 
                        {"name" : "periodTo","index" : "periodTo"}
            ]},
            {"key":"width","value": "440"},
             {"key":"sortable","value": true},
           {"key": "filterToolbar","value":{ 
                "stringResult": "false", 
                "searchOnEnter": "true",
                 "enableClear": "false"
            }},
             {"key":"jsonReader","value":{
                "root":"currencyExchangeSOs" 
            }},
            {"key":"sortname","value": "fromCurrencyCode"}
        }
    }
]
```

I am using the following code to map json with the object

```
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream src = resource.getInputStream();


         try {
             PortalModal[] portalModal = mapper.readValue(src, PortalModal[].class);
             portalDataList =  Arrays.asList(portalModal);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

PortalModal.java

```
public class PortalModal {

    private String widgetCode;
    private String widgetTitle;
    private String widgetType;
    private Boolean isAuthorize;
    private Map<String,Object> widgetAttributes; 
    private String widGetSpanNumber;
    private String jqimagePath;
    private String jqimageCount;
    private String jqimageHeight;
    private HashMap<String,String> widgetContent;


    public String getWidgetCode() {
        return widgetCode;
    }
    public void setWidgetCode(String widgetCode) {
        this.widgetCode = widgetCode;
    }
    public String getWidgetTitle() {
        return widgetTitle;
    }
    public void setWidgetTitle(String widgetTitle) {
        this.widgetTitle = widgetTitle;
    }
    public String getWidgetType() {
        return widgetType;
    }
    public void setWidgetType(String widgetType) {
        this.widgetType = widgetType;
    }
    public Boolean getIsAuthorize() {
        return isAuthorize;
    }
    public void setIsAuthorize(Boolean isAuthorize) {
        this.isAuthorize = isAuthorize;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getWidgetAttributes() {
        return widgetAttributes;
    }
    public void setWidgetAttributes(Map<String, Object> widgetAttributes) {
        this.widgetAttributes = widgetAttributes;
    }
    public String getWidGetSpanNumber() {
        return widGetSpanNumber;
    }
    public void setWidGetSpanNumber(String widGetSpanNumber) {
        this.widGetSpanNumber = widGetSpanNumber;
    }
    public String getJqimagePath() {
        return jqimagePath;
    }
    public void setJqimagePath(String jqimagePath) {
        this.jqimagePath = jqimagePath;
    }
    public String getJqimageCount() {
        return jqimageCount;
    }
    public void setJqimageCount(String jqimageCount) {
        this.jqimageCount = jqimageCount;
    }
    public String getJqimageHeight() {
        return jqimageHeight;
    }
    public void setJqimageHeight(String jqimageHeight) {
        this.jqimageHeight = jqimageHeight;
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getWidgetContent() {
        return widgetContent;
    }
    public void setWidgetContent(HashMap<String, String> widgetContent) {
        this.widgetContent = widgetContent;
    }



}
```

However I am getting the follwoing error.

```
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@1797b87; line: 9, column: 31] (through reference chain: com.qr.jadu.portal.modal.PortalModal["widgetAttributes"])
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:246)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:104)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2723)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1900)
        at com.qr.jadu.portal.core.PortalConfigImpl.initPortal(PortalConfigImpl.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
```

I dont want to use simplejson.  Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What you have is not valid JSON (due to widgetAttributes). It's unparseable, whatever the JSON parser you use.

Comment: I agree. I changed the json.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For widget attributes you will need to create a class for the key/value object and change the map to an array.  Your new object would look like this:

```
public class Attribute {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    @JsonCreator
    public Attribute(@JsonProperty("key") String key,
                     @JsonProperty("value") String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And your property on `PortalModal` will look something like this:

```
private List<Attribute> widgetAttributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<PortalModal> portalDataList;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    Map<String, Object>[] maps = mapper.readValue(
            resource.getInputStream(), Map[].class);
    List<Object> obj1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : maps) {
        obj1.add(map);
    }

    portalDataList = (List<PortalModal>) (List) obj1;
```

This code is working fine..